# Thingsboard Windows Installation Error

Tags: java, windows, installation, thingsboard

When i run the install.bat file on a windows 7 machine.  i receive the following error:

> Detecting Java version installed. Detecting if it is 64 bit machine
>   CurrentVersion Detecting if it is 32 bit machine CurrentVersion 1.8
>   Java 1.8 found! Installing thingsboard ... Error: Could not find or
>   load main class Files\thingsboard\lib\thingsboard.jar ThingsBoard
>   installation failed!

I assumed it was reading the BASE file directory incorrectly. So I it to the absolute directory location as shown below:

```
SET BASE="C:\Program Files\thingsboard"
SET LOADER_PATH=%BASE%\conf,%BASE%\extensions
SET SQL_DATA_FOLDER=%BASE%\data\sql
SET jarfile=%BASE%\lib\thingsboard.jar
SET installDir=%BASE%\data
```

I get the following error:

> Detecting Java version installed. Detecting if it is 64 bit machine
>   CurrentVersion Detecting if it is 32 bit machine CurrentVersion 1.8
>   Java 1.8 found! Installing thingsboard ... Logging system failed to
>   initialize using configuration from 'C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard\install\logback.xml'
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
>   ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogAppender] -
>   Failed to create parent directories for [C:\ Program
>   Files\thingsboard\conf\"C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log] ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogAppender] -
>   openFile("C:\Program Files\thingsboard"\logs /install.log,true) call
>   failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log (The file name, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.loadConfiguration(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:161
>   )
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initializeWithSpecificConfig(AbstractLoggingSystem.jav
>   a:57)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.AbstractLoggingSystem.initialize(AbstractLoggingSystem.java:47)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.logback.LogbackLoggingSystem.initialize(LogbackLoggingSystem.java:114)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initializeSystem(LoggingApplicationListener.java:
>   304)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.initialize(LoggingApplicationListener.java:272)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEnvironmentPreparedEvent(LoggingAppl
>   icationListener.java:235)
>           at org.springframework.boot.logging.LoggingApplicationListener.onApplicationEvent(LoggingApplicationListener.jav
>   a:208)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.invokeListener(SimpleApplicationEventMult
>   icaster.java:166)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMult
>   icaster.java:138)
>           at org.springframework.context.event.SimpleApplicationEventMulticaster.multicastEvent(SimpleApplicationEventMult
>   icaster.java:121)
>           at org.springframework.boot.context.event.EventPublishingRunListener.environmentPrepared(EventPublishingRunListe
>   ner.java:68)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplicationRunListeners.environmentPrepared(SpringApplicationRunListeners.java
>   :54)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.prepareEnvironment(SpringApplication.java:337)
>           at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:308)
>           at org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication.main(ThingsboardInstallApplication.java:42)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>           at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.MainMethodRunner.run(MainMethodRunner.java:48)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:87)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:50)
>           at org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher.main(PropertiesLauncher.java:521)
>   java.lang.IllegalStateException: Logback configuration error detected:
>   ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogAppender] -
>   Failed to create parent directories for [C:\ Program
>   Files\thingsboard\conf\"C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log] ERROR in
>   ch.qos.logback.core.rolling.RollingFileAppender[fileLogAppender] -
>   openFile("C:\Program Files\thingsboard"\logs /install.log,true) call
>   failed. java.io.FileNotFoundException: "C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log (The file name, directory name, or
>   volume label syntax is incorrect) ThingsBoard installation failed!

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes seem to be a problem.

> C:\ Program Files\thingsboard\conf\"C:\Program
>   Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log java.io.FileNotFoundException:
>   "C:\Program Files\thingsboard"\logs\install.log

Have you tried to use `SET BASE=%ProgramFiles%\thingsboard` or escape the space in the path with a ^ `SET BASE=C:\Program^ Files\thingsboard`?

## edit:

The problem is because of the space in the install dir.

I have tried to install it in "c:\test folder" and got the same problem.
There was no problem when installing in a folder without space like "c:\test"

I changed the following part in the install.bat file and was able to install it in the folder with a space.

```
SET "BASE=%~dp0"
SET "LOADER_PATH=%BASE%conf,%BASE%extensions"
SET "SQL_DATA_FOLDER=%BASE%data\sql"
SET "jarfile=%BASE%lib\thingsboard.jar"
SET "installDir=%BASE%data"

PUSHD %BASE%conf

java -cp "%jarfile%" -Dloader.main=org.thingsboard.server.ThingsboardInstallApplication "-Dinstall.data_dir=%installDir%" -Dinstall.load_demo=%loadDemo% -Dspring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=none -Dinstall.upgrade=false "-Dlogging.config=%BASE%install\logback.xml" org.springframework.boot.loader.PropertiesLauncher

if errorlevel 1 (
   @echo ThingsBoard installation failed!
   POPD
   exit /b %errorlevel%
)
POPD

"%BASE%thingsboard.exe" install
```

Comment: Hi Manuel, i just tried both of your suggestions and receive the same result --> Error: Could not find or load main class Files\thingsboard\lib\thingsboard.jar

Answer (score 0):

When I received this error, I ran the command with `Run as Administrator` and my problem was solved.

if you  receive the same result:

1. Install JRE
2. Delete the space in the installation directory
3. Run command with `Run as Administrator`